# How to create a line with large rounded caps?

Tags: html, css

I'm working to create the following seen in the design/image below.

A UI element built with CSS which is a straight line with large rounded caps. Is there a way to do this with one DIV? Or will I need to create 3 DIVS: One for the line and two for the caps?

Would love to learn the smart, elegant way to achieve this desired design. Thank you

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create the line with the caps/dots with a single div, but for the numbers below you'd need some more elements.

```css
*,
*:before,
*:after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.line {
  background: black;
  margin: 24px;
  position: relative;
  height: 2px;
}
.line:before,
.line:after {
  background: black;
  border-radius: 50%;
  content: '';
  position: absolute; left: 0; top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  width: 12px; height: 12px;
}
.line:after {
  left: auto; right: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="line"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

use pseudo classes ::before and ::after

```
<span class="line"></span>

.line {
  display: block;
  height: 4px;
  width: 100px;
  background-color: #000;
  position: relative;
}
.line::before,
.line::after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #000;
  height: 10px;
  width: 10px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  top: -3px;
}

.line::before {
  left: 0;
}

.line::after {
  right: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
.lineDot{
  width:400px;
  height:4px;
  background-color:#000;
  position:relative;
  margin:20px;
}

.lineDot:before, .lineDot:after{
  display:block;
  content:'';
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  width:20px;
  height:20px;
  background-color:#000;
  border-radius:50%;
  transform: translate(0, -8px);
}

.lineDot:before{
  left:0;
}

.lineDot:after{
  right:0;
}


<div class="lineDot"></div>
```

here a working pen: 
https://codepen.io/anon/pen/pMNJGo